# Unhandled exception at 0x00051526 Access violation reading location 0x00000004

Tags: c++, memory

```
class ByteBuffer
{
public:
    ByteBuffer(std::shared_ptr<uint8_t> buf, int len);
    explicit ByteBuffer(int len);
    virtual ~ByteBuffer(void);

    std::shared_ptr<uint8_t> getBuffer() const {return this->buffer;}
    uint16_t getLength() const {return this->length;}
private:
    std::shared_ptr<uint8_t> buffer;
    uint16_t length;
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ByteBuffer::ByteBuffer(std::shared_ptr<uint8_t> buf, int len)
  : buffer(buf),length(len)
{ }

ByteBuffer::ByteBuffer(int len)
  : buffer(new uint8_t[len]),length(len)
{ }

ByteBuffer::~ByteBuffer(void)
{ }

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Packet
{
public:
    explicit Packet(ByteBuffer& ref);
    virtual ~Packet(void);
};

Packet::Packet(ByteBuffer& ref)
{
    // how do i intinlize it here so i can use it?
}

// i have onther method for the handling 
void HandlePacket(Packet & pack);
Handel(ByteBuffer & ref)
{
    Packet p(ref);
    HandlePacket(p); // the error happens here
}
```

Edit: sorry i forgot to add the Method where the error happens my bad sorry

as you can see the 2calsss, but every time am trying to pass the bytebuffer inside the packet then use the packet inside onther method it gives me this error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00051526 in AccountServer.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.

so my question how can i solve this prob!?

Comment: What makes you think `shared_ptr<>` is even usable with pointers allocated with `new[]` without a custom deleter?

Comment: @ildjarn shared_ptr handles it when it hates zero it will delete it automatic thats why am using smart pointers

Comment: @Mixed `shared_ptr` without a custom deleter cannot be used to delete pointers allocated with `new[]`, use `shared_array` for that.

Comment: @Sam Miller- i have updated my question now maybe it's clear!

Comment: Just use `std::vector<>` for your buffer (instead of `ByteBuffer`), that's *exactly* what it's for.

Comment: @Mixed **Do not** use `shared_ptr` with pointers allocated using `new[]`. Doing so invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @GMan ByteBuffer it's a class LOL!?

Comment: @MixedCoder : In case it's not clear, `shared_ptr<>` `delete`s the pointer, not `delete []`s it as is needed for an array.

Comment: sure, but I think in the simple case of uint8_t that won't cause the problem stated here. I might be wrong though.

Comment: @frag: It's always undefined behavior, type doesn't matter. `new` matches `delete`, `new[]` matches `delete[]`.

Comment: @GMan true, I don't support that practice, but I don't think that is what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

What's happening is you are accessing the address `0x4`.  Probably some object is `NULL` and you've tried to de-reference it with something like `ptr[1]` or the `->` operator.

Run your program under a debugger and it will be clearer what's happening.  In particular it will give you a stack trace and tell you about the state of local variables.

As is mentioned in the comments, you can't use `new []` with `shared_ptr` in the way that you're expecting, since `delete` is different from `delete []`.  See this website, which came up in a Google search: http://nealabq.com/blog/2008/12/02/array_deleter/ .  You will need a customer deleter which does `delete []` instead of the default, which is just `delete`.