# Access violation when leave method

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I'm trying to figure out how to fix my access violation when I leave a method. I changed from using unique ptr to shared ptr so maybe it's a subtlety of shared_ptrs.  I'm having trouble finding info on shared_ptrs online.  I also used to have the commented out line below and had to change it to use my new class instead of using the vector of objects of unique ptrs. It doesn't have the access violation when I uncomment the curly brackets.

The method looks like this:

```
int ExecuteIt(String& sFileName, String& sInput, String& sOutput)
{
    // make sure we have valid data
    if (sFileName.isEmpty() || sInput.isEmpty() || sOutput.isEmpty())
    {
        return -1;
    }

    int iResult = -1; // error

    CreateDocW(sOutput, sFileName, pWriter, pDeleteWriter);

    CreateDocR(sInput, sFileName, pReader, pDeleteReader);

    //{

    shared_ptr<IFJ> m_spIFJTemp = pReader->vMethodImpl1();

    if (m_spIFJTemp && !m_spIFJTemp->isVectorIfdEmpty())
    {
        //auto RootContainerIter = vDocRootContainers->begin();
        pWriter->vMethodImpl2(m_spIFJTemp);
        //pWriter->vMethodImpl2(move(*RootContainerIter));

        iResult = 0; // Success
    }
    //}
    Cleanup(); //before step into cleanup m_spIFJTemp has shared_ptr {m_spVectorIFD={ size=1 } } [2 strong refs] [make_shared]  std::shared_ptr<IFJ>
        //after cleanup m_spIFJTemp has shared_ptr {m_spVectorIFD={ size=??? } } [1 strong ref] [{_Uses=1 _Weaks=1 }]   std::shared_ptr<IFJ>

    return iResult;  //when I uncomment the extra curly brackets it steps 
                         //into a memory _Decref() and has access violation
                         //reading location in _Destroy() 
}
```

Cleanup is like this:

```
void Cleanup()
{
    // Cleanup the reader
    if (pDeleteReader != nullptr)
    {
        pDeleteReader();
        pDeleteReader = nullptr;
    }

    // unload the reader
    if (pReaderLibHandle != nullptr)
    {
        dlclose(pReaderLibHandle);
        pReaderLibHandle = nullptr;
    }

    // Cleanup the writer
    if (pDeleteWriter != nullptr)
    {
        pDeleteWriter();
        pDeleteWriter = nullptr;
    }

    // unload the writer
    if (pWriterLibHandle != nullptr)
    {
        dlclose(pWriterLibHandle);
        pWriterLibHandle = nullptr;
    }
}
```

I found this info [accessviolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182443/unhandled-exception-at-0x00051526-access-violation-reading-location-0x00000004) online but I checked and I don't create any shared_ptr with new and I've been trying to look at it in the debugger and I'm not sure about the strong ref's to the shared_ptr.

Please let me know if you have any input as to what could be causing this.  I would appreciate any helpful response.

Comment: Did you step through the code in the debugger, and look at the call stack?

Comment: The shared pointer will `delete` `m_spIFJTemp` when the shared pointer goes out of scope. Is that what `vMethodImpl1` mandates? Does it state that *you* now own that pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cleaned things up so the shared_ptr didn't have an issue when it left scope:

```
m_spIFJTemp.reset(); /* remove shared_ptr referece before calling destructors */
Cleanup();
```

Another thing that would have worked is to call Cleanup after leaving the ExecuteIt method.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know which class `pReader` is referring to, but I suspect the following:

You put the result of `pReader->vMethodImpl1()` into a shared pointer. This means when you leave the method this shared pointer will call `delete` on that pointer.

However I suspect that `vMethodImpl1()` does not give up "ownership" of the object that is returned and keeps a reference within `pReader` and when you call `Cleanup` then `pReader` is destructed and itself calls `delete` on the pointer that you stored in the shared pointer. Therefore you try to destruct that object twice.

I would suggest that you just use

`IFJ* m_spIFJTemp = ...`

instead of

`shared_ptr<IFJ> m_spIFJTemp = ...`

and then use `valgrind` or another tool to check if the memory is actually freed.

Comment: When I did the that, it just has an access violation when it exits the if statement instead.  IFJ* m_spIFJTemp = pReader->vMethodImpl1().get();
   
    if (m_spIFJTemp && !m_spIFJTemp->isVectorIfdEmpty())
    {
        //auto RootContainerIter = vDocRootContainers->begin(); shared_ptr<IFJ> foo(m_spIFJTemp);
        pWriter->vMethodImpl2(foo);
        //pDocWriter->vMethodImpl2(move(*RootContainerIter));

        iResult = 0; // Success
    } //access violation here now

Comment: Going back to the original version in my question, it looks like the shared_ptr to IFJ contains a shared_ptr of a vector of shared_ptr IFD.  It looks like the shared_ptr IFD might not be transferring it's memory correctly. When I leave vMethodImpl2(), it's shared_Ptr IFD goes away.  I think it tries to delete it again when it leaves the method scope.

Comment: You get an access violation in your first example (your first comment) because again you store the pointer into a shared_ptr. If you leave the if then this shared_ptr calls `delete m_spIFJTemp` so when you leave the function again there is a second delete. If you do NOT use ANY shared_ptr but only the IFJ* then it should work.

Comment: I see why you might want a `shared_ptr` ... perhaps your `vMethodImpl2` expects a shared_ptr as an argument. In that case you can create a `shared_ptr` that does not call `delete` by defining a custom "deleter" function that does nothing. This technique is explained in the following link: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html#static

Comment: It's true.  The second method, vMethodImpl2, needs a shared ptr.  I guess I could have gone through everything and not used the shared ptr, but we are trying to use shared_ptr's to use their functionality.  What I would up doing is below.